# Avoiding use of XMVECTOR in XNAMath

Tags: c++, directx, directx11

I don't want to use XMVECTOR which i currently use in my DirectX 11 C++ game code.
Because it is too much for me in memory.
I want to use XMFLOAT3 or 4, but **the problem is there is no matrix/vector XNA Math function available for XMFLOAT***. It is pointless to use 6 fields or pass to the shader (XMVECTOR), if object represents only 3 or 4 (and operate with them only).

I don't want to convert types in any case just to do calculations. Can you please recommend me what to do? I really like using XNA math, but XMVECTOR is just dirty variant...

Comment: Update: i no more using _XM_NO_INTRINSICS define because __m128 is SSE extension and much faster than __vector4 struct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMVECTOR is superbly optimized, packed and aligned, etc... I doubt it is causing you any real trouble. You're probably prematurely optimizing something that is not on the hot-path or in the memory-hog part of your application. I'm also pretty sure that when using XMVECTOR loaded with an XMFLOAT4 you only pass 4 variables to the GPU.

Comment: I do not use __m128. I am using _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_ definition of XMVECTOR. So you think it is okay to use 6 floats instead of 3 for each vertex in buffers? For me just unprofessional looking at least. Currently i pass XMVector to shader, in layot defined as "float3". Hope it is correct.

Comment: Why do you think you have a float6 in your shader or sent that there?

Comment: I was incorrect. XMVECTOR is 16 bytes size (_XM_NO_INTRINSICS_) -- 4 floats. It is fine. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

While I still recommend to use `XMVECTOR` & `XMMATRIX`, if you really don't want to use them you can find `XMFLOAT` wrappers for vector/matrix math in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) (SimpleMath.h).

These wrappers use `XMVECTOR` & `XMMATRIX` as well, it's just hidden from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLoadFloat3 and XMStoreFloat3 to convert your storage-oriented XMFLOAT3 uses into usage-oriented XMVECTOR values and back again.  The code is ugly, but it works.  If you're doing non-trivial math kernels (which you should strive for) it's more efficient this way, too, if you leave SIMD on.